# Pass Switch button value

Tags: android

I'm working on the game, when I want the user to be able to switch on hints. I have a switch button in my MainActivity and I want to pass the value when the button is switched ON, to the GameActivity and there code what I need. I have been trying to do this for some time now and couldn't find answer to this.

```
public void passSwitch(View view){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(
            "com.quiz.myquiz", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putBoolean("state", hintSwitch.isChecked());
    editor.apply();
}
```

I'am calling this method on the xml onClick.

Comment: "I'am calling this method on the xml onClick." You should show this code as well as the code which starts `GameActivity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the easy way to pass data between Activity's

`Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), GameActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("state", true);
startActivity(intent);`

Then in your GameActivity

`Boolean state = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("state");`

Comment: ye that works  but it opens the activity, i don't want to open the activity when the swich button or check box button is pressed i just want to pass its value to another activity

Comment: Well, so then retrieved the data from your shared preference.

Comment: @j.doe of course you do not want to start the game activity immediately. You send the data in the same intent that you already create to start the second activity. This is probably in the onClick() for some other button.

Comment: `boolean state = getSharedPreferences(
            "com.quiz.myquiz", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("state")’    inside your GameActivity

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using save preferences, simply call back the values where necessary like

```
getSharedPreferences("com.quiz.myquiz", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("state", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `passSwitch()` method saves the setting. Now you need to load the setting when `GameActivity` starts.

Alternatively, `MainActivity` can pass the setting in the Intent which you use to start `GameActivity`.

Comment: can you provide some example of how to pass the switch button with intent to the other activity?

Comment: i don't want to start another activity with this button i want to pass its value and if button is checked i want to code in my game Activity

Comment: @j.doe You do this whenever you are ready to start the second activity. That does not have to be immediately after the switch is changed.

Comment: now when i press the button it opens another activity, how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @j.doe When do you want to start GameActivity? Do you have a button to start the game?